# How do I swap odd elements in array of a String? Eg: Input: I Love India Output will be: I voLe dnIia

Tags: java

How do I swap odd elements in Array of a String? Eg:  Input: I Love India  Output will be: I voLe dnIia

```
package com.String;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class swap_odd_element {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1= "I Love India";
        String[] arr= s1.split(" ");

        for(String s2:arr)
        {
            if(s2.length()>1)
            {
                char[] arr1= s2.toCharArray();
                int len=arr1.length;

                for(int i=0; i< len;i++)
                {
                     char temp=arr1[i];
                      arr1[i]=arr1[i+2];
                     arr1[i+2]= temp;
                     String swap = new String(arr1);

                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(s2);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: you can use `reverse()`  in java after splitting.

Comment: What if there are three odd elements?

Comment: the famous IOBE  meet u here `[i+2];`

Comment: @ikegami  They are even elements/:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, huh? I'm asking what the program should do return when the input is `Moscow`? What about for `eagleowl`?

Comment: @ikegami isn't India consisting of three odd elements? Or am I misunderstanding what an odd element is? (Letters on odd indexes?)

Comment: Input: aaa bbb ccc ddd
output:ccc bbb aaa ddd

Comment: @Aidin, oh indeed. But it still doesn't answer what to do with four, which I asked in a followup comment. What should `axbxcxdx` become? (`bxaxcxdx`? `bxaxdxcx`? `dxcxbxax`? Something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
a        => a
ax       => ax
axb      => bxa
axbx     => bxax
axbxc    => bxaxc
axbxcx   => bxaxcx
axbxcxd  => bxaxdxc
axbxcxdx => bxaxdxcx
```

What you call the odd elements are actually those at even positions since 0-based indexing is used.

```
Indiana
0123456  i
0123012  i % 4
0101010  i % 2
```

So,

```
If,             Use the element at
(i % 2) == 1    i
(i % 4) == 0    i+2
(i % 4) == 2    i-2
```

Except we gotta watch prevent a swap with a non-existent character.

```
If,                        Use the element at
(i % 2) == 1               i
(i % 4) == 0 && i+2 ≥ n    i
(i % 4) == 0 && i+2 < n    i+2
(i % 4) == 2               i-2
```

So,

```
String word = "...";
char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(chars.length);
int n = chars.length;
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
   int i_mod_4 = i % 4;
   buf.append(chars[
         i_mod_4 == 0 ? ( i+2 < n ? i+2 : i )
       : i_mod_4 == 2 ? i-2
       :                i
   ]);
}

word = buf.toString();
```